# Playing an pre-recorded audio file to somebody over a call

Tags: android, media-player

I understand that even though the AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL is available in the SDK for android, it is not actually been used to play a pre-recorded audio file, or atleast that is what i have heard/seen on the internet.  My Question is this, if this is truly the way it is, how is prankdial accomplishing this?

Many similar questions have been asked but they all seem really old, so i was wondering if anybody has gained any more insight about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My Question is this, if this is truly the way it is, how is prankdial accomplishing this?

It is impossible. Android applications do not have access to the in-call audio stream. `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` is for volume control.

Comment: so, how is prankdial doing it?

Comment: @Vishnui: Possibly by using their own Web service. On some devices, you can also use speakerphone mode to get a low-quality way of playing audio where the other caller can hear it.

Comment: This is something that they really need to fix.  i guess i'll just have to go with the speakerphone solution.  Thanks for answering!